# autoresize textarea field after entering text dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a  which is filled by javascript.
The text inserted to the textarea is dynamic and can have different length, thus I need the textarea to be dynamically resize after the javascript entered the text.
I would like the textarea to have max width and if it's field the text will continue to fill in the next line causing the textarea height to grow.

How do I achieve such thing ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize

May be what you need and add a max-height to the text-area CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this: https://jsfiddle.net/paulistoan/84ujn5qp/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#textArea").on("input", updateText).trigger($.Event("input"));
 
 function updateText()
 {
  $("#textDiv").text($(this).val() + "\n");
  $(this).css("width", $("#textDiv").width()+2);
  $(this).css("height", $("#textDiv").height());
 }
});
```

```css
textarea {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border: medium none;
  color: black;
  outline: medium none;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color:lightgray;
  resize: none !important;

  outline-color: inherit;
  outline-style: dashed;
  outline-width: 2px;
}

#textDiv {
  top: 50px;
  background-color:#FF0004;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: pre;
  display: none;
}

textarea, #textDiv {
  font-family: Impact, Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
  font-size: 26px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="textArea">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,&#10;consectetur adipisicing&#10;elit porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum</textarea>

<div id="textDiv"></div>
```

And use the max-width CSS property on the textarea, #textDiv and change **white-space: pre** to **white-space: pre-wrap**